# What do we call a person who doesn't like to stay at home?

Tags: names

What do we call a person who doesn't like to stay at home? That loves outdoor activities and most of his hobbies are outside?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean physical activities or social activities?

Comment: "*Nature Lover*" is commonly used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A word I often hear to describe such a person is 'outdoorsy' but I wasn't sure if it was a real word or slang. However, it does appear in many online dictionary references and does indeed appear to have been around a while.

> Of, associated with, or fond of the outdoors:
>   Bill is such an outdoorsy kind of guy

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outdoorsy
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/outdoorsy
http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outdoorsy

Answer (score 2):

A *socialite* : (from Wikipedia)

> - is a person who has a reputation in society for spending a significant amount of time participating in social activities such as parties and other fashionable events, entertaining guests and being entertained by others of similar standing.

Comment: That is not consistent with what OP asks.

Comment: OP question is not specific. I think it may fit The description given.

Comment: Only if the parties you mention are held outside. OP is asking for someone that spends the majority of his time "outside" which I strongly assume is nature rather than "not his own home". That the other answer was accepted seems to support this assumption

Comment: This might be considered the opposite of a *homebody*, but the OP seems to be asking for something more like *outdoorsy*.

Comment: This and *extrovert* were what popped into my head from the question title. I agree, however, that the actual question has less to do with leaving home than being outdoors.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very non-specific.  At first it sounds as though the person needs to socialise a lot and then the 2nd sentence sounds like they just want to be outside.

If it's just outside then what sort of thing?  Just in the garden?  Walks in parks?  Is it an excuse to go down the pub?

Sociable covers feeling more comfortable in the company of others?  Some would describe that as being neurotypical.

If the person feels panicky or very uncomfortable indoors and just walking down the high-street helps then they might be claustrophobic.

I think people need more detail about exactly what the question means because it's just toooo vague and apparently possibly even self-contradictory at the moment.

Regards from 
Tom :)

Comment: Hi :)  hmm, i think outdoorsy just about covers it.  It's a 'bit' posh though.  Jolly hock-sticks what what!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are more aiming for someone who just doesn't want to be at home, instead of more specifically enjoying the outdoors, you could say that they get "stir crazy" if they spend too much time at home. (*Feel bored, restless, anxious, trapped in their confined environment*)

Honestly, this question reminded me of the game *The Sims 3*, in which a sim would get `stir crazy` if they didn't leave the house for a week. I also have heard it used in actual conversation to describe someone who feels like they just *need* to leave the house... though probably only a couple times in my life (*very rarely*).

[Stir Crazy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir-crazy)

From merriam-webster: `distraught because of prolonged confinement`

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stir_crazy_(condition)) [*citations needed*]

**History** *(headings are my own)*

"Used among inmates in prison, it referred to a prisoner who became mentally unbalanced because of prolonged incarceration. The term "stir crazy" is based upon the slang stir (1851) to mean prison."

**Current Use**

"It is now used to refer to anyone who becomes restless or anxious from feeling trapped and even somewhat claustrophobic in an environment, perceived to be more static and unengaging than can any longer continue to hold interest, meaning, and value to and for them."

Answer (score 0):

- A [fresh air fiend](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/fresh-air-fiend)
  is a person who likes to be outside.
- A person who is afraid to be in enclosed spaces
  is [claustrophobic](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/claustrophobic),
  or a [claustrophobe](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/claustrophobe).
- A related term, [agoraphile](http://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/agoraphobia),
  may mean a person who prefers to be in open spaces,
  although it is [also defined](http://www.definition-of.com/agoraphile) (as slang)
  as “A person who experiences sexual excitement from being outdoors.” 
  Whether this is a “real word” is debatable; many dictionaries don’t list it at all.